# Duplicate Browser History State - Router Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

**I am using Beta (resources they have on the official tutorial)**

In my Angular app, when navigating the app at certain points I will have to click back twice in order to actually go back - almost as if the same page is being pushed to browser history twice.

I can't figure out if this is an Angular 2 bug or if I have something funky going on in my code.

For instance, the following URL, whether entered directly into the address bar or navigated to in the app, will require pushing the back button twice in order to actually go back: http://localhost:3000/products/strollers (product-list.component).

Here is some code that I *think* is relevant:

**app.component.ts**

```
// imports and whatnot
// ...

@Component({
    selector: 'rz-app',
    templateUrl: 'app/views/wrap.html',
    directives: [
        ROUTER_DIRECTIVES,
        NavComponent,
        CartWidgetComponent,
        PreloaderComponent
    ],
    providers: [
        ROUTER_DIRECTIVES,
        NavServices,
        CartServices,
        FavoriteServices
    ]
})


@RouteConfig([
    {
        path: '/',
        name: 'Home',
        component: TilesComponent,
        useAsDefault: true  
    },
    {
        path: '/home',
        name: 'Home',
        component: TilesComponent,
    },
    {
        path: '/categories',
        name: 'Categories',
        component: CategoryComponent
    },
    {
        path: '/category/:slug',
        name: 'Category',
        component: ProductListComponent
    },
    {
        path: '/pro-shop',
        name: 'The Pro Shop',
        component: StorefrontComponent
    },
    {
        path: '/world-traveler',
        name: 'The World Traveler',
        component: StorefrontComponent
    },
    {
        path: '/products/:slug',
        name: 'ProductsList',
        component: ProductListComponent
    },
    {
        path: '/products',
        name: 'Products',
        component: ProductListComponent
    },
    {
        path: '/product/:slug/:id',
        name: 'Product',
        component: ProductComponent
    }
])

export class AppComponent {
```

**product-list.component.ts**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'rz-product-list',
    directives: [SortComponent, SearchComponent, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
    pipes: [SortPipe, SearchPipe],
    templateUrl: 'app/views/products-list.html'
})


export class ProductListComponent {  
    // default title
    title = 'Product';
    products;
    sortValue;
    searchValue;

    /* for rz-sort */
    sort_options = [
        {
            label: "Lowest Price First",
            sortBy: "points",
        },
        {
            label: "Highest Price First",
            sortBy: "-points",
        },
        {
            label: "Brand Z-A",
            sortBy: "-brand",
        },
        {
            label: "Brand A-Z",
            sortBy: "brand",
        },
        {
            label: "Product Name Z-A",
            sortBy: "-name",
        },
        {
            label: "Product Name A-Z",
            sortBy: "name", 
        }
    ];

    // constructor of services
    constructor(
        private _router: Router, 
        private _routeParams: RouteParams, 
        private _favService: FavoriteServices
    { }

    // initialize
    ngOnInit() {

        var _param;
        _param = this._routeParams.params.slug;

        this.getProducts(_param);
        this.title = _param;
    }

    // ...

 }
```

**index.html**

```
<html>
  <head>

    <base href="/">

    <title>Sriracha!!!</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">   

    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,300italic,400italic,600,600italic,700,700italic,800,800italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/pure/0.6.0/pure-min.css"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/pure/0.6.0/grids-responsive-min.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/assets/css/structure.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/assets/css/styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/assets/css/skins/minimal.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/assets/css/skins/tiles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/assets/css/skins/usb.css">

    <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
    <!-- IE required polyfills, in this exact order -->
    <script src="node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/es6/dev/src/testing/shims_for_IE.js"></script>   
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/router.dev.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/http.dev.js"></script>
    <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
    <script>
      System.config({
        packages: {        
          dist: {
            format: 'register',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
          }
        }
      });

      System.import('dist/main')
            .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
    </script>
  </head>
  <!-- 3. Display the application -->
  <body>
    <rz-app>
      <!-- Can't use preloader component here :( -->
      <div class="preloader-modal">
        <div class="preloader-content">
          <img src="dist/assets/images/preloader.gif"/>
          <p>Loading...</p>
        </div>
      </div>  
  </rz-app>
  </body>
</html>
```

No idea what's going on, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

**for the discontinued router**

That's a known issue. The router is currently being reworked anyway.

- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5025
- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5025
- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6641

Comment: did this issue has been fixed or is it still pending? I'm getting this error too on angular2 stable version

Comment: There were at least 2 router rewrites since then. The issues were all closed because the router they were addressing isn't maintained anymore. I haven't found a similar issue for the current router. If you can reproduce in a Plunker please create a new bug report.

Comment: I do have same issue on our website with latest stable version of angular, which is not RC anymore. but I'm not sure how to reproduce it, I'm not expert in angular2.